# Menu and all pages content from database

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm writing simple website with some cms functions. It would be good to have all menu items and pages contents held in database.

I have table with `id`, `name`, `parent_id` and a `content` field. In future I would maybe move content to a `content` table to have multiple contents to menu item with fk. But it is not the case here.

The question is:

1. Do I need the URL field in menu table?
2. What else do i need to get it to work? Should every page have its own controller? I,m a beginner with `zend framework`, so please give me some directives. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with Question 2: every page does not need its own controller. If your pages are static you can even load every page using a single action. For more dynamic processing you could use a separate action for each page.

In any case, make sure you structure your code into controllers and actions in a way that makes sense. For example, inside your CMS a user might edit, create or delete a post. You could then create a `PostController` inside which you write an `editAction`, `createAction` and `deleteAction`.

You *could* store the URL in the table, but you do not necessarily have to.

**Single action approach (mostly for static content)**

Make sure the page `id` or `name` is stored in a GET param. You could then use the following code:

```
public function genericpageAction()
{
    $thePageID = $this->_request->getParam('id');

    // fetch the page content from the db based on $thePageID
    // and pass it to the view
}
```

Of course, here, you could also match against the URL stored in the table if you chose that approach.

**Multiple action approach (for more dynamic processing, most likely what you want with a CMS)**

You could define a route for each page and load its content in the respective action. For example, for the page to edit a post:

```
class MyCMS_PostController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function editAction()
    {
        // fetch the home page content
        // do any further processing if necessary
    }
}
```